# Multidatacenter Replication with Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdb-ruby, rethinkdb-javascript

I have two servers in two different geographic locations (alfa1 and alfa2).

r.tableCreate('dados', {shards:1, replicas:{alfa1:1, alfa2:1}, primaryReplicaTag:'alfa1'})

I need to be able to write for both servers, but when I try to shutdown alfa1, and write to alfa2, rethinkdb only allow reads:  Table test.dados is available for outdated reads, but not up-to-date reads or writes.

I need a way to write for all replicas, not only for Primary.

Is this possible ?  Does rethinkdb allow multidatacenter replication ?

I think that multidatacenter replication need to permit write for both datacenters.

I tried to remove "primaryReplicaTag" but system don't accept !

Any help is welcome !!!

Comment: Hey @Carlos would you mind closing this?

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB does support multi-datacenter replication/sharding.

I think the problem here is that you've setup a cluster of two, which means that when one fails you only have 50% of the nodes in the cluster which means you have less than 51%.

From the failover docs - https://rethinkdb.com/docs/failover/

> To perform automatic failover for a table, the following requirements
>   must be met:
>
> - The cluster must have three or more servers
> - The table must be configured to have three or more replicas
> - A majority (greater thanhalf) of replicas for the table must be available

Try adding just one additional server and your problems should be resolved.

Comment: "Majority" does not mean "51%."  It means "more than 50%."  The reason 1/2 isn't a majority is not because `0.5<0.51` but because `0.5<=0.5`.  Consider, for example, a group of 101 servers out of 200: that _is_ a majority, but it's less than 51%.